# Hebrew letters Hey-Yud-Dalet after a name

Tags: hebrew, names, acronyms

I'd seen some stuff written about a man, with the Hebrew הי"ד (Hey-Yud-quotes-Dalet) after his name.  What does that mean?

Comment: Largely subsumed by the later http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6309.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57818

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stands for "Hashem Yikom Damo" -- "may God avenge his (her/their) blood."  Used after the name of a Jew who was murdered.

Comment: The correct words are "Hashem Yikom Damav"

Comment: @Yahu, we say _nikmas **dam** avadecha hashafuch_.

Comment: how do you spell it in hebrew?

Comment: @max ה' יקום דמ(י)ו

Answer (score 12):

The correct words are "Hashem Yikom Damav". We refer to the murder of one person as "Shefichas Damim" , the blood being plural.

Update:

I just saw in the daf yomi that there is discussion about why the Torah uses the plural regarding the blood of Hevel (Abel) when he was killed by Cain. One answer given is because when one is killed, all his potential future descendants are also "killed". Hence, Hashem Yikom Dam**av**, G-d shall avenge his "bloods". That is why we refer to murder as "shefichas dam**im**".

Comment: Way to add Torah content to a simple grammatical note!

Comment: Mishna Sanhedrin 4:5 is the source he refers to.